# How to use Atlas Search to find a text containing a subtext

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have a collection hosted on Atlas,

I currently have declared an Atlas Search index with the default configuration, but I am unable to use it to find documents that partially matches the text.

For instance, I have the following documents :

```
    [
  {
    _id: 'ABC123',
    designation: 'ENPHASE IQ TERMINAL CABLE 3PH-1 UD',
    supplierIdentifier: 205919
  },
  {
    _id: 'DEF456',
    designation: 'ENPHASE CABLE VERT IQ 60/72CELLS 400VAC',
    supplierIdentifier: 205919
  },
  {
    _id: 'GHI789',
    designation: 'P/SOLAR PC ASTROENERGY 275W 60 CELULAS',
    supplierIdentifier: 206382
  }
]
```

If I use the text search to search "EN", Nothing is returned :

```
[{ "$search" : { "index" : "default", "text" : { "query" : "EN", "path" : { "wildcard" : "*"}}, "count": {"type": "total"}}}]
No result
```

But if i use the regex search, my documents are correctly returned :

```
db.testproducts.aggregate([{ "$search" : { "index" : "default", "regex" : { "query" : "(.*)EN(.*)", "allowAnalyzedField" : true, "path" : { "wildcard" : "*"}}, "count": {"type": "total"}}}])
[
  {
    _id: 'ABC123',
    designation: 'ENPHASE IQ TERMINAL CABLE 3PH-1 UD',
    supplierIdentifier: 205919
  },
  {
    _id: 'DEF456',
    designation: 'ENPHASE CABLE VERT IQ 60/72CELLS 400VAC',
    supplierIdentifier: 205919
  },
  {
    _id: 'GHI789',
    designation: 'P/SOLAR PC ASTROENERGY 275W 60 CELULAS',
    supplierIdentifier: 206382
  }
]
```

As the regex operator is pretty slow, how to achieve the same with the text search ?

Answer (score 0):

Gfhyser, you have a few options and I'm not sure which one you will like the best as they both have limitations.

**Option 1**, you can specify a path. As you can imagine, wildcard paths and leading ad trailing regex can be expensive. If you know the path you want search is `designation`, performance will be better if you change your existing query to:

```
db.testproducts.aggregate([{ "$search" : { "index" : "default", "regex" : { "query" : "(.*)EN(.*)", "allowAnalyzedField" : true, "path" : "designation", "count": {"type": "total"}}}])
```

**Option 2**, you can refine your search. Ask yourself if you are truly looking for Enphase and Energy wherever they appear in the same result.

**Option 3**,The final option is somewhat experimental for me because I need to spend more time on it. I simply want to help. It might be the best performing, involves you reversing your tokens indexed and when querying with a custom analyzer because it can speed up leading wild card queries.If you don't mind a bit of complexity, here is how it would look. Let me know if works out as I don't use regular expressions as much these days.

I create a custom analyzer in the `sample_airbnb.listings_and_reviews` dataset to search with leading wildcard characters. The index looks like:

```
{
  "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "name": [
        {
          "dynamic": true,
          "type": "document"
        },
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "summary": {
        "analyzer": "fastRegex",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "charFilters": [],
      "name": "fastRegex",
      "tokenFilters": [
        {
          "type": "reverse"
        }
      ],
      "tokenizer": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And a query that exploits this speed and has the flexibility to potentially match both of your desired terms would look like this:

```
[
  {
    '$search': {
      'index': 'reviews_search', 
      'compound': {
        'should': [
          {
            'wildcard': {
              'query': '*cated*', 
              'path': 'summary', 
              'allowAnalyzedField': true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: When I try to use this custom analyzer in json editor, I get an error: "Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 500"